# what is the equivalent of SAS-parameterestimates in R

Tags: r, parameters, sas

Please how can this be written in R

```
proc glm data=DataTX;
class DAG;
by HID;
model Bwt = DAG/ss3 solution;
ods output parameterestimates =TX_BW_corrFact;
```

run;

Comment: WHat does it do? And you should probably ask this kind of Q on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: You'll have more luck in getting an answer to this if you tell us what your code does, and also provide sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to `proc glm` for most purposes in R is `lm`, which fits linear models. It looks like you want the estimated coefficients from the model(s), which can be obtained by `coef(mod)` where `mod` is the object returned by `lm`.

The most complicated bit is replicating the `by` statement, which fits separate models for each level of the `by` variable (`HID` in this case). Try something like this. I assume you've already got your dataset imported into R.

```
grps <- split(DataTX, DataTX$HID)
mods <- lapply(grps, function(x) lm(Bwt ~ DAG, data=x))
sapply(mods, coef)
```

This splits `DataTX` into separate groups based on `HID`. For each group, it then fits the model `lm(Bwt ~ DAG)`. The last line then extracts the fitted coefficients for each model.

This can be concatenated into a single line, but leaving it as 3 separate statements probably makes it easier to follow.

Note that the coefficients won't be the same as those from SAS, because of differences in how the two systems parametrise the model. In particular, SAS by default treats the last level of a class/factor variable as the reference, while R uses the first.

Comment: Hi Hong Ooi, your script gives me only one estimate for DAG but  DAG has different levels, how can I get a separate estimate for each level of the DAG. Thanks

Comment: Let me guess, DAG is numeric? Then lm will treat it as a continuous variable. Turn it into a factor (the equivalent of a SAS class var) with `DataTX$DAG <- factor(DataTX$DAG)` and rerun.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at lmList() from the lme4 or nlme package

```
library(lme4)
lmList(Reaction ~ Days | Subject, sleepstudy)
```

That is shorter than Hong's solution.

```
grps <- split(sleepstudy, sleepstudy$Subject)
mods <- lapply(grps, function(x) lm(Reaction ~ Days, data=x))
sapply(mods, coef)
```